# Google people API i cant get the email addresses

Tags: google-people-api

```
        gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
       'resourceName': 'people/me',
       'pageSize': 120,
       'personFields': 'names,phoneNumbers,emailAddresses'
     })
```

[i already specify emailAddresses as one of my personfields but i dont see email address in the response as shown below.[this is the response in console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uajqx.png)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I have the same problem, even though my scopes are setup correctly and in fact, I am able to get email through React Native library. Just not the web-based API call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer to this. The problem was in defining the SCOPE for your call. I am using the google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient method of asking for user authorization (see a slightly different [example here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js))

So, this was the correct way of asking for authentication:

```
this._googleTokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
         client_id: this._googleClientId,
         scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
         callback: '',
      });
```

See the TWO scopes I requested.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe check if your scopes allow you access to email addresses and if that contact actually has an email address. I believe the API doesn't even add a field if it's empty, rather than populating a field with an empty value.

Answer (score -1):

The required scope for these fields are:
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`